# UITableView animation glitches when inserting and deleting a row of custom cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am having a tough time with inserting and deleting a row in the tableView.

Basically my tableview is a list of sections. When user taps on the section, more rows will be added to the bottom of the section and vice versa on delete.

```
section
-- row
-- row
section
section
```

Inserting/deleting a row with default cell size works like a charm. However the animation gone haywire when I try to insert a custom cell.

On slow motion, the cell appears **before** the row completes its "expansion".
I have found the exact problem from another member but the solution doesn't work at all.

Here's the video from him.. and it's exactly what I am experiencing..
http://vimeo.com/58063609

and here's his post for reference: [UITableView animation glitch when deleting and inserting cells with varying heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492335/uitableview-animation-glitch-when-deleting-and-inserting-cells-with-varying-heig)

Does anyone have idea on how to fix this problem? I have been struggling for days.. any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Have you tried to set clipsToBounds to YES on the table view cells content view?

Comment: yes I tried that already.. doesn't work.

Comment: The UITableViewRowAnimationFade option can help smooth jarring transitions like this.

Comment: I also tried the Fade option.. but it's still very obvious that the cell appears before the row completes expanding. Looks pretty bad.

Comment: I'm not sure there's an easy solution for this. Have you considered leaving expanded sections open, rather than only having one open at a time? Fewer things moving at once can be less confusing for users. I put together an example project in the [TLIndexPathTools](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools) library on GitHub that does both ways. Try running the "Collapse" project. It looks pretty good to me even when the cell height is bumped up to 100px in the storyboard. It also optimizes the scroll position when expanding a section, which is nice.

Comment: thanks.. I took a look at the Collapse project and it does seem like it's doing the same thing as mine? Cells are overlapping while expanding/collapsing.

Comment: Yes, when "Single Expanded Section" is enabled, there is some visible overlap, though it looks acceptable to my eye. I wasn't sure if you were seeing exactly the same thing in your project.